# cors package send status instead of error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I am trying to use `cors` package in `node` and `express` environment to verify if requesting domain can access my resources. That part was not a problem following official documentation. The problem however is with response. If domain is not allowed to access - `cors` is sending error with stack trace (paths to files). Can this be avoided and just respond with status 401, something like `res.status(401).end()` ? I tried that but it gives me error because headers were already sent.

```
const cors = require("cors");

const corsOptions = async (req, callback) => {
    let domain = getDomain(req);
    if (domain === false) {
        return callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }

    const isWhitelisted = await client.get(domain).catch(err => { console.log(err); });

    if (isWhitelisted !== undefined) {
        callback(null, true);
    } else {
        callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

So i was hoping to replace `callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));` this part with just sending status 401 and ending stream so no errors with stack are printed in the client.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done, according to the source code what you are sending in `callback` as `err` is passed in the `next` function like

```
if(err) next(err);
```

But there is one easy workaround to what you want.

The `cors()` is returning a middleware(a function with three params req, res and next). So you can wrap the cors in your middleware and return whatever you want. If all the things are perfect you can use the `cors`.

```
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require("cors");

const corsMid = (req, res, next)=>{
        const trueVal = true;
        if(trueVal){
            res.status(400).send("Error")
        }else{
            return cors()(req,res,next);
        }
}
app.use(corsMid);

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.json('Hello World');
})

app.listen(8080, ()=>{
    console.log('started')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround is you can construct the `Error` on a variable first, then remove the `stack` property from the error variable:

```
let err = new Error('Not allowed by CORS')
err.stack = ""
callback(err)
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```js
import cors from 'cors';

export const devCorsOptions: cors.CorsOptionsDelegate = (req: any, callback: any) => {
    const ipAddress = req.socket.remoteAddress;
    if (ipAddress === '<WHITELISTED_IP>') callback(null, true);
    else callback(req.res.status(403).json({ message: 'Forbidden!' }), false);
};
```

this will return a json response **but mostly** a `403` status code.
[image]